# Many to many relationship in a QGIS Geopackage - fail

Tags: qgis, sql, database, geopackage

The current user manual has been unsuccessful in directing me to establish a many to many db relationship in a geopackage in QGIS (3.10.2 on Ubuntu w gdal 2x).

After the [airlines in the manual crashed and burned](https://docs.qgis.org/3.4/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/attribute_table.html#vector-relations), (at the point of entering sql instructions in dbmanager, python errors and on subsequent tries a locked up gpkg file) I'll run my own example;

Say we have `cats` and `fleas` and good humans want to keep track of the instances where fleas occupy more than one cat and cats have more than one flea. We are not interested in the flea2flea interactions.

Please note my example and this use case has no spatial data, the tables are set up without geometry column. The fleas are blind and won't be enlightened about mobility until they get the results of the analysis which I haven't completed...

Table of cats with a primary key (text 50)(widget UUID)
Table of fleas with a primary key (text 50)(widget UUID)
Pivot table with two fields, foreign_key_cats foreign_key_fleas
(gpkg writes it's own fid for each of the above, I am leaving it alone)

Define 2 x  relations in project properties

`Name: indx_cats Parentlayer:cats Parentfield:cats_pk Childlayer:pvt childfield:fk_cats`
`Name: indx_fleas Parentlayer:fleas Parentfield:fleas_pk Childlayer:pvt childfield:fk_fleas`

In the layer properties for cats and fleas, set the `attribute form` to `drag and drop designer`. Move the indx_cats and indx_fleas across to the layout section (in each of their layers). Set the `cardinality` option to pk_cats for the fleas layer and vice versa.

In the `form widget` setting for the primary key fields, put the `widget type` to `UUID Generator`.

In the cat layer, enter a new record by using the pencil icon to enter edit mode and click on the icon to add record. The dialog will show the primary data entry and then a child entry below. Click the pencil in the child to turn it to edit mode. Click the `Add child feature` to achieve that. It appears that a record has also been generated for fleas. It is visible that the UUID generator has worked on the child. Save edits and click OK, twice. Dialogs are completed and closed.

On inspection, there is a new record in each of the three tables. However the important one, the pivot table, **only captures one of the keys**, for the cat. The field in the same row for the fk_fleas is empty. A subsequent join via the pivot table appears unachievable.

What have I done wrong?

Comment: fyi, if I use the inbuilt primary key for the source tables, fid, as the target for the relation, it copies to the pivot table the result `AUTOGENERATE` in both fields.

Comment: You need to commit the changes, by saving the edits or leaving the edit mode.

Comment: Also, why are you trying to populate a new relation from the cats layer and not from the pivot layer?

Comment: thanks  Gabriel De Luca  but I have paid a lot of attention to that. Only thing I could change is the order in which I save and close. Does it matter? I have not found any difference in my trials.

Comment: The pivot layer does not lead to any child dialog.

Comment: One thing I had overlooked, was to "enable transaction mode" in PROJECT|PROPERTIES|DATASOURCES.   But this didn't make it any better.

Comment: I have replicated your schema and found the same behavior. In the log there were some warnings. But I could fill the pivot layer by selecting existing or creating new cats and fleas.

Comment: I have just followed the example out of the Qgis Manual for the same thing in postgis (I also searched up the `manual in development' it is not different).  The postgis version is more promising, but won't work as yet. It readily adopted the Relationships after setting them up in sql code and has the benefit of fully functioning primary keys. Current problem is it won't save the edits (new records).

Comment: Thank you @Gabriel . You mean fill the full row of the pivot layer successfully?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/104803/discussion-between-gabriel-de-luca-and-bjw).

Comment: You're trying to do in a desktop GIS GUI what a relational database with ease.

Depending on the number of users who will be viewing the data, I still suggest building a simple web application.

Comment: Thanks @DPSSpatial, I'm wanting to prototype the structure, trial it with some data first before going to development. I can there being a lot of trivial tables, but with more experience they will probably become redundant.